# Performance difference between C++ and C# for mathematics

Tags: c#, c++, performance

I would like to preface this with I'm not trying to start a fight. I was wondering if anyone had any good resources that compared C++ and C#  for mathematically intensive code? My gut impression is that C# should be significantly slower, but I really have no evidence for this feeling. I was wondering if anyone here has ever run across a study or tested this themselves? I plan on running some tests myself, but would like to know if anyone has done this in a rigorous manner (google shows very little). Thanks.

EDIT: For intensive, I mean a lot of sin/cos/exp happening in tight loops

Comment: For what its worth, sometimes you can squeeze a little more speed out of C# using unchecked operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691349%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I would say use the one that suits better. And if it's C#, and you have performance problems, you can still rewrite the bottlenecks in c++ or even asm.

Comment: Numerical computations? Have you considered FORTRAN? http://www.lahey.com/lf71/lfnet.htm

Comment: +1 Remus -- We're comparing a Mustang with a Camaro when there's a Ferrari in the garage...

Comment: @Austin: Love that analogy. Of course... there are four separate keys to the Ferrari that each have to be inserted and turned at the precise moment, or the damn thing won't start. Oh, and the clutch is behind the seat.

Comment: Well there are plenty of people who have no business behind the wheel of a Ferrari... (Wait, is that a C analogy??)  :-P

Comment: I'd think of SIMD math in C as more like a Suzuki Hayabusa: unbeatable speed and performance if you know exactly what you're doing, and if you don't -- street pizza.

Comment: I haven't used C# in a long time, but I'm pretty sure you can use unsafe code to do SIMD in C# as well (assuming the JIT doesn't do this automagically for you).

I'm assuming the C# compiler & JIT is on par w/ Java (reasonable assumption I think), so you should be seeing about native performance for pure math.

Comment: Why does everyone assume that their JIT has magic powers of SIMD vectorization? Even a native compiler with maximum opt flags does a mediocre job of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have to periodically compare the performance of core math under runtimes and languages as part of my job.

In my most recent test, the performance of C# vs my optimized C++ control-case under the key benchmark — transform of a long array of 4d vectors by a 4d matrix with a final normalize step — C++ was about 30x faster than C#.  I can get a peak throughput of one vector every 1.8ns in my C++ code, whereas C# got the job done in about 65ns per vector.

This is of course a specialized case and the C++ isn't naive: it uses software pipelining, SIMD, cache prefetch, the whole nine yards of microoptimization.

Comment: Glad to help, but please remember that I'm citing a specific case here -- one particular kind of linear algebra, where I'm comparing C#' JIT output to my carefully hand-optimized-and-almost-assembly C++.

Answer (score 13):

C# will be slower in general, but not significantly so. In some cases, depending on the structure of the code, C# can actually be faster, as JIT analysis can frequently improve the performance of a long-running algorithm.

**Edit:** Here's a nice [discussion of C# vs C++ performance](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2009/01/03/debunking-c-vs-c-performance/)

**Edit 2:**

> "In general" is not really accurate. As you say, the JIT compiler can actually turn your MSIL into faster native code that the C++ compiler because it can optimize for the hardware it is running on.

You must admit, however, that the act of JIT compiling itself is resource intensive, and there are runtime checks that occur in managed code. Pre-compiled and pre-optimized code will *always* be faster than just JITted code. *Every benchmark comparison shows it.* But long-running processes that can have a fair amount of runtime analysis *can* be improved over pre-compiled, pre-optimized native code.

So what I said was 100% accurate. For the general case, managed code is slightly slower than pre-compiled, pre-optimized code. It's not always a significant performance hit, however, and for some cases JIT analysis can improve performance over pre-optimized native code.

Comment: "In general" is not really accurate.  As you say, the JIT compiler can actually turn your MSIL into faster native code that the C++ compiler because it can optimize for the hardware it is running on.

Comment: Of course, there is going to be some penalty due to runtime checks... so perhaps "In general" wasn't misleading :)

Comment: "Pre-compiled and pre-optimized code will always be faster than just JITted code" - This is false. JITs have access to dynamic information that a static compiler does not. It can use this information to perform [i]dynamic[/i] optimizations. Something a static compiler can not do.

Comment: Oh, actually you metnion "for some cases JIT analysis can improve performance over pre-optimized native code." which I do agree with :) It's just your earlier quote (which I mentioned above) seems to conflict with this.

Comment: @Falaina: What you quoted is 100% accurate. Read it again. But what you said wrote afterward **is also** accurate, and if you read further into my post, I acknowledge it. JITters have access to runtime analysis that can improve performance. But only after runtime analysis, and only if the assembly stays loaded and/or runs continuously. If you have, for example, a small command line program that computes a quick computation, C++ wins, every time. If you do the Fibonacci Sequence on a server, however, a well-coded C# program can outperform C++.

Comment: Heh... looks like we cross-posted. Ignore the "read it again" snark. Also ignore the "said wrote" part -- I wrote "said" and decided to change it to "wrote" but failed. :)

Comment: I do admit, that is why I left the second comment :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice your comments until I had done the edit. I type too slowly, I guess. Or too much. :)

Comment: I don't think runtime checks apply to any mathematical stuff, aside from bounds checks with matrix multiplication or other array stuff (which can be avoided entirely with unsafe code).

Comment: That "nice discussion" is crap (I'm a C++ programmer).  He's using std::sort to sort the data structure, which is actually accepting the array by-reference.  Instead of doing the same thing in C# (Java is smart enough to convert calls to new as stack allocations when the object scope is limited to a funcion - I'm sure C# is similar), he's having it do a copy every time & then acting surprised that performance sucks.

If you write crappy code, your performance is going to blow.

Comment: I would argue that it would always be faster in C++ (or faster in fortran). The reason being if you are doing a highly computational intensive task that is going to take a long long time then you have already experimented and found the appropriate compiler settings to optimize the code for the specific hardware you are using. Of course that's what the JIT is doing automatically at runtime and it the C++ programmer gets the flags wrong then C Sharp will win. But if you want really fast then use fortran its still a decade ahead on optimization for numerical applications.

Comment: @Martin York: Optimizing C++ is less about compiler switches/flags and more about the compiler's capability and the structure of the code. The compiler can only interpret certain blocks of codes in certain ways; a poorly structured loop, for example, is unlikely to be unrolled by the compiler. Inlining is not guaranteed, even with hints. JIT analysis, on the other hand, can look at the history of a loop execution and modify the compilation to unroll it, or choose to inline larger methods than might have been inlined by the compiler. Will this always work? No. But the possibility *is* there.

Answer (score 6):

You do not define "mathematically intensive" very well (understatement for: not at all).

An attempt to a breakdown:

- For the basic Sin/Cos/Log functions I would not expect much difference.
- For linear algebra (matrices) I would expect .NET to loose out, the (always enforced) bounds checking on arrays is only optimized away under some circumstances.

You will probably have to benchmark something close to your intended domain.

Answer (score 5):

For straight mathematical functions asking if C# is faster than C++ is not the best question.  What you should be asking

> Is the assembly produced by the CLR JITer more or less efficient than assembly generated by the C++ compiler

The C# compiler has much less influence on the speed of purely mathmatical operations than the CLR JIT does.  It would have almost identical performance as other .Net languages (such as VB.Net if you turn off overflow checing).

Answer (score 5):

There are extensive benchmarks here:

http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=csharp&lang2=gpp&box=1

Note this compares the Mono JIT to C++. AFIAK there are no extensive benchmarks of Microsoft's implementation out there, so almost everything you will hear is hearsay. :(

Comment: no extensive benchmarks of Microsoft's @ iirc the license doesn't allow publication of benchmarks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're asking the wrong question.  You should be asking if C++ on  can beat out the .NET family of languages in mathematical computation.  Have a gander at F# timing comparisons for [Runge Kutta](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/1/6/f-has-better-performance-than-c-in-math.html)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I understand that all .NET languages go to IL and then to machine code

Comment: +1 for using the right language for the job.  Great evidence in the link.

Comment: For what it's worth, it appears that F# can not only easily translate into parallel processes but also can optimize repetitious tasks such as what you see in that link.  I'd say it's not as wonder as the link makes it out to appear but it's pretty darn exciting to see done on an interpretted language.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [Mono.Simd](http://go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?tlink=0@N%3aMono.Simd) to accelerate some operations. The minus is that on MS runtime it's not accelerated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked recently, but the last time I did check, Microsoft's license agreement for the .NET runtime required you to agree NOT to publish any benchmarks of its performance. That tends to limit the amount of solid information that gets published.

A few others have implied it, but I'll state it directly: I think you're engaging in (extremely) premature optimization -- or trying to anyway.

Edit:
Doing a bit of looking, the license has changed (a long time ago, in fact). The [current terms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973265.aspx) 
say you're allowed to publish benchmarks -- but only **if** you meet their conditions. Some of those conditions look (to me) nearly impossible to meet. For example, you can only publish provided: "your benchmark testing was performed using all performance tuning and best practice guidance set forth in the product documentation and/or on Microsoft's support Web sites". Given the size and number of Microsoft's web sites, I don't see how anybody stands a chance of being certain they're following all the guidance they might provide.

Although that web page talks about .NET 1.1, the newer licenses seem to refer back to it as well.

So, what I remembered was technically wrong, but effectively correct anyway.

Comment: Well, its not premature if its a 2x slowdown for mathematically complex code. That's avoiding a time trap

Comment: Does not address the question at all, -1

Comment: Jerry, do you have a link to that restriction (or discussions about it) ?

Comment: Ed, it addresses the question (are there any studies...) **very well**.

Answer (score 1):

For basic math library functions there won't be much difference because C# will call out to the same compiled code that C++ would use.  For more interesting math that you won't find in the math library there are several factors that make C# worse.  The Current JIT doesn't support SSE instructions that you would have access to in C++.